# How to capture image from Tab using node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, opera, image-capture

I am developing application using Node.js. I want to capture image and store it in DataBase.
If i use OPERA mobile 12.10 ,how can I use this with Node.js?

Comment: Do you mean capture screenshot of a webpage?

Comment: I want to capture object like hard copy, not a webpage using TAB.

Comment: What object do you want to copy? A screenshot of the webpage, an image embedded in a website or what? Note also that node.js is server-side software, not something you can run on a browser.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It is trivial to take screenshots of webpages with phantom (see this example: [technews.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/technews.js))

As a basic approach:

- Call server function for making a screenshot from your browser (for instance `jQuery.post`)
- Create server code in node.js that handles the request
- Launch phantomjs as a child process when handler is called and store the result in the database